# Create Video Playlist Manually (not from sd card)

Tags: android, android-listview

Anyone know how to create video playlist manually on android?
and how to play it?
I want to play video from that playlist not from sd card/internal phone.

and how to play video from listview?
listview code:

```
int[] indexVideo = {R.raw.saya,R.raw.anda,R.raw.aku,R.raw.dia,R.raw.kita,R.raw.lupa,R.raw.makan,R.raw.bahagia, R.raw.bisa, R.raw.belanja,R.raw.pergi,R.raw.pulang,R.raw.minum,R.raw.duduk};
```

How to play all of these video in listview?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the videos are on the SD card is irrelevant.  How would you show the list of videos if they *were on the SD card?  If you have the answer to that question, then just do the exact same thing, except with your apk resident videos.

Reference this question to see how to display thumbnails of the videos:
[how to display video thumbnails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260488/how-to-display-video-thumbnails)

and then just play the videos the user selects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
I don't need to display tthumbnails of the videos

Comment: you don't need "a lot" of video players. You need exactly one video player. If you don't need thumbnails then it's even easier. Just play your videos in the video player! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm beginner in android. can you give me an example(code) please.

Comment: I need to play videos in sequence without clicking next button or others. Thanks

Comment: use the onComplete listener to be alerted to when your video has ended and then play the next one.

Comment: How to declare 'play the next video'?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Media Player](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) page of Android developer. You could use

```
create(Context context, int resid)
```

method to create MediaPlayer for your Resources. and

```
start()
```

method to start your first media, after that you can also use

```
setNextMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer next)
```

to play your next Resource by creating new MediaPlayer for it

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if I have a lot of videos then I have to make a lot of new MediaPlayers? is there way to make it simple?

Comment: I didn't use MediaPlayer that much, so I don't really know. I just used it for one file before. but there is a selectTrack() method, so I think there might be a way to do it for with just MediaPllayer

Comment: do you know how to put all the track URI's to a List and play them as single tracks?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't "make a lot of new MediaPlayers" as you stated in a previous comment. You should have exactly two, the one playing and the next one so it can prepare in advance.

I offer the following with no guarantee it will work (because I haven't tested it), but it should give you an idea how to proceed:

```
private int[] mPlaylist = new int[] { /* Your raw resource IDs */ };

private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(final Context context, final int index) {
    if (context == null || index < 0 || index >= mPlaylist.length) return null;
    MediaPlayer newPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, mPlaylist[index]);
    newPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            if (what == MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START)
                mp.setNextMediaPlayer(createMediaPlayer(context, index + 1));
        }
    });
    newPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    return newPlayer;
}
```

Then somewhere appropriate (like `onStart`) you will need to call `createMediaPlayer(yourContext, 0);`.